# How to output coordinates from a shapefile to a GMT or CSV file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, coordinates, csv

I want to get the coordinates for a line shapefile as csv or gmt files.

I click create "new layer" - "new shapefile layer" - I check the "line" box and then "OK". Then I make my shapefile. When I move the cursor I can see the coordinates at the lower bar but when I create a new shapefile and look in the attribute table there is no coordinates.

How to get the all the coordinates for the shapefile?

Comment: Where is your shapefile located? It may be in a protected folder, in which case you can copy/paste the shapefile (and it's associated files) into another location such as a folder in your desktop. You should be able to load this shapefile and do a **Save As...**.

Comment: I have tried to copy/paste the files but I still get the "premission denied". 

I need the coordinates for the shapefiles which I can read manually if I use the identifying tool. Is it possible to extract just the coordinates?

Comment: I opened the .dbf and the only thing showed was the id, no coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I should have asked if the shapefile already had coordinates stored in it. Apologies, my mistake. In QGIS, click the **Edit** icon for the shapefile and open up the Field Calculator. Create a new column with a name like "X-Coor" or something and in the expression box, type `$x`. Repeat for the "Y-Coor" with the expression `$y`. Open up the Attributes table, select all rows and then select the option "Copy selected rows to clipboard". Open up Excel or Notepad etc and paste the values.

Comment: When I try this I get the error "no root node! Parsning failed?" (freely translated).

Comment: Something doesn't seem right. In QGIS, can you create a new shapefile (save it on desktop), load your other shapefile, copy all the attributes and paste it into your new shapefile? Then repeat the process mentioned earlier?

Comment: Please detail the steps you used to add the shapefile, and if it is displaying properly. What kind of a geometry is it (point, line, etc)?

Comment: I click create "new layer" - "new shapefile layer" - I check the "line" box and then "OK". Then I make my shapefile.

Comment: I have changed the question but I don't know if it is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Geometry Export to CSV** function on your shapefile to obtain coordinates via:

*MMQGIS* > *Import/Export* > *Geometry Export to CSV*

Make sure it is enabled in *Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins...*

Comment: This seems to be a good way, unfortunately I get: "Failure opening //temp-nodes.csv" Something seems wrong with my shapefile

Answer (score 3):

There is a native (non-plugin) solution within QGIS:

1. Right-click on your shapefile layer and select "Save as".
2. Select CSV format;
3. Deselect "Add saved file to map";
4. Under "layer options", select GEOMETRY AS_XY (for point files) or GEOMETRY AS_WKT (for points, polygons or lines).

For point files only, this will output a CSV file with an X and Y column in the correct projection.

[image]

If AS_WKT is selected, the geometry will be given as a string of coordinates in WKT format, i.e. for a simple line:

```
LINESTRING (-22.777090612886717 30.458186615233615,14.586239123711941 8.17857147600256)
```

However, what would be even easier in some cases is just to select the features in the QGIS canvas, click "Copy" then paste into a spreadsheet or text editor, giving you the WKT geometry directly!

Comment: I have tried this, still no coordinates for X and Y, just the id.

Comment: @Johnston, please see my comment in the original post above; there must be something else going on and more information is needed!

Comment: @Johnston, see my edit - XY works for points only, but you can select WKT and get a file with all the coordinates for the geometry listed; alternatively, copy-and-paste as indicated!

Comment: @Johnston, did this work?